# How can I find only base nodes of an XML file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have an xml file with various nodes and want to get first nodes of it, not children. Here's my code:

```
function processXML(event:Event):void {
    menu_xml = new XML(event.target.data);
    trace (menu_xml.child("mainmenu"));
}
```

This code doesn't display anything. I'm using Flash Professional CC 2015.0.

**EDIT:** Here's the xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<mainmenu>

    <home/> 
    <portfolio/> 
    <contact/> 
    <friends>

        <joe/> 
        <karen/> 
        <bob/> 

    </friends>

</mainmenu>
```

**EDIT 2:** I need to get only these strings: home, portfolio, contact, friends.

Comment: read this: [Reading external XML documents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6a.html)

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. I don't have any problem with loading the file. I just can't get the nodes I want.

Comment: `home`, `portfolio` and `contact` are all empty, you won't get a result from them unless you give them children and/or attributes.

Comment: @onurcano22 - sorry :) `for each(var itemName:XML in menu_xml.elements()) {
    trace (itemName.name());
   }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `menu_xml` is the base node, by calling `menu_xml.child("mainmenu")` you are seeking for XML like this:

```
<mainmenu>//menu_xml
    <mainmenu/>//menu_xml.child("mainmenu");
</mainmenu>
```

Obviously this doesn't exist and the function returns an empty XML record. Your data set:

```
<mainmenu>//menu_xml = new XML(event.target.data);

    <home/>//menu_xml.child("home"); 
    <portfolio/> //menu_xml.child("portfolio"); 
    <contact/> //menu_xml.child("contact"); 
    <friends>//menu_xml.child("friends"); 

        <joe/> //menu_xml.child("friends").child("joe"); 
        <karen/> //menu_xml.child("friends").child("karen"); 
        <bob/> //menu_xml.child("friends").child("bob"); 

    </friends>

</mainmenu>
```

EDIT: To get the node names you will have to loop through the XML object structure, by looping through the result of the `children()` you will be able to use the `name()` function to get the name of each child of the root

```
for each (var node:XML in menu_xml.children())
{
    trace(node.name());
}
```

output:

```
home
portfolio
contact
friends
```

For more information about Traversing XML structures in AS3, I recommend the [AS3 Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. so how can I get only these nodes: home, portfolio, contact, friends.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean. Is xml structre affected if I get the names? Well, what I'm trying to do is converting a fla file written in AS1 to AS3. And there are some lines like: **node_xml.childNodes[i]** and **menu_xml.firstChild**. I edited the question. thanks again.

Comment: the xml structure is unchanged. your just looping through it. `childNodes` and `firstChild` no longer exist. These are handled through the `children()` function, so `firstChild` would be `children()[0]` and `childNodes[i]` would be `children()[i]`

Comment: I've added a link to the answer that should help you with moving through XML structures in AS3

Comment: wow! I added "each" after "for" and it worked fine. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

trace("Data loaded."+menu_xml );